# Check value without control structure

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to solve a problem I've got on my homework.

How can I check if a value is within a range, e.g. 1 ≤ value ≤ 31, without using if, switch, or any other control structure, in Java?

Comment: wow, didn't use my offical account because I asked for a friend of mine but it seems you guys really like this question SO <3

Comment: Sorry about tagging as homework and then removing. I didn't get the notice that it was too meta!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// Zero if valid, non-zero otherwise
int n = (int) Math.floor((value - 1) / 31.0);

// Convert any non-zero value to -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) without any boolean logic.
n |= n << 1;  n |= n >> 1;    
n |= n << 2;  n |= n >> 2;
n |= n << 4;  n |= n >> 4;
n |= n << 8;  n |= n >> 8;
n |= n << 16; n |= n >> 16;

// Value is either -1 or 0. Switch -1 to +1.
n = -n;

// Use array indexing to simulate a conditional.
String[] results = {"valid", "invalid"};
System.out.println(results[n]);
```

See it run at http://ideone.com/98sA8.

You could even extend this to run different code paths:

```
Runnable[] options = {
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("valid");
        }
    },

    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
};

options[n].run();
```

See it run at http://ideone.com/sUKiW.

Comment: I think boolean logic was not ruled out. Only control structure operating on booleans.

Comment: Nice. The math are interesting (esp. the flip at the end), but I really like the way this answer *shows the use of a look-up* to avoid a branching syntax construct -- this can be expanded to an object look-up and method dispatch (e.g. imagine the array contained Runnable objects): `Runnable[] results = ...; results[-n].run()`

Answer (score 7):

```
(value-1)-((value-1+31)%31)
```

0 means true, anything else means false.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the check to a boolean and then print that boolean out:

```
boolean checkValue = (1 <= value && value <= 31);
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use java assertions for validation but if it fails, you'll get an AssertionError. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html.

Comment: @seanizer - given the question, nothing non-awful can be provided. And this one would work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically this does not use control structure:

```
boolean isWithinRange = value >= 1 && value <= 31;
```

but then if you want to use the boolean variable, you'd need a control structure.

There can be some way by using a class that throws an exception when certain conditions are not met (for example a buffer with size of 31), and then catch the exception, but internally this class would be also using a control structure.

So my answer is - no, you can't - you'll always need a control-structure, even if it is hidden in some class' implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A probably silly solution:

```
Arrays.asList("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10," +
    "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20," + 
    "21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31").split(",").
    contains(Integer.toString(value));
```

Comment: `contains` has an 'if' inside ;)

Answer (score 1):

Does the ternary operator count as a control structure? It behaves like an `if` statement but it is used as an operator rather than a standalone statement:

```
System.out.println((1 <= value && value <= 31) ? "valid" : "invalid");
```

Comment: I think the ?: is a disguised control structure.

Comment: sure, it's just a short version of `if x return a else return b`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is send the value to a server using sockets. Then have a real person check the condition and let him/her send you back the answer(true, false).

You can use an [ObjectInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to receive the answer as a Boolean object since a Boolean object implements Serializable, you can avoid the use of if. Just cast the received object to your boolean variable.